# Rails - Stop serving any front-end views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a Ruby on Rails API that is not supposed to serve any front-end related views.

What would be the way to tell Rails not to consider serving any content of the views directory if possible?

Comment: Can you just delete the views directory and all the files in it? If it isn't there, you can't server it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 

Comment: Why do you want to tell Rails not to consider any content (I guess you only mean HTML content) from the `views` directory? Why isn't having tests for that not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the new app, use: `rails new my_api --api`. Read more about it: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#creating-a-new-application

For the existing app – the first steps would be (for rails 7 app):

1. Replace `require "rails/all"` within `config/application.rb` with required railties/engines:

```
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
# require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

2. Introduce a namespace for the API controller or update the base application controller like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
...
end
```

3. verify cors configuration `config/initializers/cors.rb`